# Preventing mesh from entering negative Y space when animating in edit mode

Tags: animation

When animating my mesh, I can't figure out how to keep it from going past the zero degree on the Y axis. You can see I made a plane to visualize this, how her feet do not move into negative territory on the first frame but they do in subsequent frames. Adding a rigidbody to the plane only works, of course, when playing the animation but not in edit mode.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "animating in edit mode"? Seems like you should constraint bones rather than worry about mesh.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't too clear. Well, just take a look at the picture. I'm making an animation in edit mode versus playing the animation once it's finished.

Comment: If you don't want the feet to pass through the floor you could use a Limit Location constraint, but I'm not convinced it's very useful or convenient...